# Interaction effect 2x2

Tags: interaction

I have a little question about a 2x2 design that keeps on confusing me. If I have this kind of 2x2 design where I can have these combinations in the conditions.

No/No, Yes/No, No/Yes, Yes/Yes. The interaction effect is the effect of the two IVs, right? As the Yes/Yes condition consist of both IVs, is the Yes/Yes condition here the same as the interaction effect of A and B?

[image: 2x2]

Answer (score 1):

No single cell of the matrix, or condition, contains the interaction effect. The interaction is that the effect of one variable depends on the level of the other variable. So you can't observe it's magnitude in a single cell. Further, don't the "no" cells contain a level of the IV? It's incorrect to say that only the yes/yes cell contains both IVs.

Suppose in your case the IV is a disease. The disease is only present in the yes/yes cell. But the IV, while perhaps labelled the same as the disease, is a variable and is about the *presence* of the disease and is not the disease per se. (further, most disease can only be defined when most people don't have it)

In your particular case the Difference between yes and no for condition `A` depends on whether `B` is a yes or a no.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The conditions do not consist any magnitude; it's just yes or no. For example: medication A yes/no, medication B yes/no. They're either exposed to it or not.

Comment: So change "disease" in what I wrote to "medication". I assumed your matrix above would result in 4 numbers of your DV and you were showing the IV to DV relationships. The differences in those dependent variables are effects of the medication. If that's not what you mean then you really need to clarify your question. The interaction is the effect of the IVs *on* the DV, *not* some property of the IV itself.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your model looks something like this:

$$Y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{A}A + \beta_{B}B + \beta_{AB}AB + \varepsilon$$

where $A$ and $B$ are both coded $0/1$, then if:

$A=0$ and $B=0$, $Y=\beta_{0}$
$A=1$ and $B=0$, $Y=\beta_{0} + \beta_{A}$
$A=0$ and $B=1$, $Y=\beta_{0} + \beta_{B}$
$A=1$ and $B=1$, $Y=\beta_{0} + \beta_{A} + \beta_{B} + \beta_{AB}$ $\longleftarrow$ interaction comes into play

There are other ways to specify such interactions, but I *think* this is what you are after.

I should also point out that coding categorical variables 0/1 when they are being used in interactions with ordered or continuous variables leads to biases due to artificial heteroscedasticity being introduced. You can get around this using something called [*effect coding*](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/effect.htm) for your nominal and categorical variables.